# Which is the fastest way to scan files in FAT32 disk?

Tags: c++, windows, disk, fat32

I want to scan FAT32 disk (I just need file path and file name) as soon as possible in C++,
Scan every files on FAT32 disk.
Is there any API to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread: [How can I quickly enumerate directories on Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511672/how-can-i-quickly-enumerate-directories-on-win32)

It actually describes FindFirstFile/FindNextFile, but if you need it faster you should go Kernel.
The index solution described in the thread will however not work for FAT32 systems - *credit MSalters*

Comment: Note that the index solution hinted at in your thread assumes NTFS chnage journals; the FAT32 in this topic excludes that option.

Comment: thanks MSalters. I changed my answer to include this. Although, my main reason to post this was to check the other thread out :)

Answer (score 0):

The term "scanning" isn't very well defined. Do you want to read each and every byte of each and every file? The easiest way is to use a directory list. Start by pushing the root directory. Then, as long as the directory list is not empty, call `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile` to enumerate all files and subdirectories. Add subdirectories to the directory list, and read the files you encounter.

Update: For your purposes, `FindFirstFileEx(FindExInfoBasic)`  would suffice. You still would want to process only a single directory at a time (breadth-first) instead of entering subdirectories as soon as you see them (depth-first). This is faster because FAT32 directory entries in a single directory are stored together, but subdirectories are typically not stored adjacent to the parent directories.