# How to read disk file entries faster than FindFile API?

Tags: winapi, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a set of file names quickly on NTFS volumes, ideally via its MFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203573/finding-a-set-of-file-names-quickly-on-ntfs-volumes-ideally-via-its-mft)

Hi,

Looks like the FindFile win32 API is slow when you need to read all files/folders in the harddisk, Any alternatives? Read **NTFS** entries directly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203573/finding-a-set-of-file-names-quickly-on-ntfs-volumes-ideally-via-its-mft