# how to read ntfs master file table using c++

Tags: c++, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I want to enumerate all the files on a disk. I am using WinAPI FindFirst/FindNext for enumeration. But this method is taking a alot of time. I read somewhere that we can enumerate very fast by reading the ntfs master file table which contains all the information regarding every file on the disk. Is there any API or some method in c++ to read the ntfs master table?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511672/how-can-i-quickly-enumerate-directories-on-win32

Answer (score 0):

There is no C++ library functionality which would be OS specific, since this would not run on other platforms, or against other file systems.

What you are really looking for is Windows API functions, not std C++ library functions.

Your best source for that kind of information might be the the Linux NTFS file system driver which is actually a Linux user space file system.

Comment: yes i am looking for Windows API. Is there any windows API for that?

Comment: As I said, there is a WIndows API for that.  The is no standard C++ functionality for that, since it's Windwos specific. 

I also suggested that you have a look at the Linux NTFS driver since it must interact with the Windows NTFS file system.  Therefor, it must have quite a detailed knowledge of reading and writing to the NTFS file system descriptor tables without actually using the Windows API.